# Cannot add fragment class to my Android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am doing a project on android studio. The problem is I cannot add a fragment class to my project. I was able to add two fragment classes when I started doing this project. But, after completing about half of my project, now I cannot add a third fragment class. When I add a third fragment class and run my project, this exception pops up:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzaa; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa' appears in /data/data/com.hashcoder.eegoomain/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.android.gms-play-services-basement-10.0.1_d1c25087bea669c827e484b09b1949315ba5fc5f-classes.dex)
     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5172)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4767)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:153)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

And I tried both `android.app.Fragment` or `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. Both doesn't work.....

Comment: We need to see your code.

Comment: I am afraid there is no code to show you because I haven't used that fragment class anywhere. I just added it to my project.

Comment: @JayeshBabu what do you mean you just added ?

Comment: I mean like this: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B53mEbqUPxJAajlGZWhHV1hGMkU

Comment: @JayeshBabu that is because of `google-play-service` check this [link](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/258)

Comment: thanks.. let me check that link..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.Make a java class and extends it from Fragment.
This is the basic structure of a fragment class.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.<your xml layout>, container, false);

        //Do your work here
        return view;
    }
}
```

and make sure you extends it from android.support.v4.app.Fragment